# Facebook Native Ads with RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to implement Facebook Native Ads by including them as an alternative view in my RecyclerAdapter. Has anyone had any experience with this? I've included my entire class for good measure.

```
public class FeedRecyclerAdapter extends LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter implements AdListener {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_FEED = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 2;

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Feed> feedItems;
    private final ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader;
    private FeedItemClickListener feedItemClickListener;
    private boolean isLongPressed = false;

    private NativeAd nativeAd;
    private NativeAdsManager manager;
    View adView;

    public FeedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feedItems, ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader, NativeAd nativeAd, NativeAdsManager manager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        this.feedItemImageLoader = feedItemImageLoader;
        this.nativeAd = nativeAd;
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_FEED:
                return new FeedViewHolder(new FeedItemView(context));
            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                return new AdditionalHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ad_test3, parent, false));
        }

        return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }

    public class AdditionalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected LinearLayout templateContainer;
        protected ImageView blank_holder;
        private LinearLayout nativeAdContainer;
        private LinearLayout adView;
        private AdChoicesView adChoicesView;
        ImageView nativeAdIcon;
        TextView nativeAdTitle;
        TextView nativeAdBody;
        MediaView nativeAdMedia;
        TextView nativeAdSocialContext;
        Button nativeAdCallToAction;

        public AdditionalHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            //// Add ad into the ad container.
            nativeAdContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_unit);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            adView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_test3, nativeAdContainer, false);
            nativeAdContainer.addView(adView);

            // Create native UI using the ad metadata.
            nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
            nativeAdTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
            nativeAdBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
            nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
            nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
            nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_FEED) {
            bindFeedItemView((FeedViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_AD) {

            AdditionalHolder new_holder = (AdditionalHolder) viewHolder;
            try {
                new_holder.templateContainer.removeViewInLayout(adView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();
            try {
                adView = NativeAdView.render(context, nativeAd, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_300);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new_holder.templateContainer.addView(adView);
            new_holder.blank_holder.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Setting the Text.
            new_holder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
            new_holder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
            new_holder.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
            new_holder.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());

            // Downloading and setting the ad icon.
            NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
            NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, new_holder.nativeAdIcon);

            // Download and setting the cover image.
            NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = nativeAd.getAdCoverImage();
            new_holder.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

            // Add adChoices icon
            if (new_holder.adChoicesView == null) {
                new_holder.adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
                new_holder.adView.addView(new_holder.adChoicesView, 0);
            }

            nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(new_holder.adView);

        }
    }

    // Differentiate between feedItem views and nativeAds
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType = 1;
        if ((position % 9 == 0) && position != 1) viewType = 2;
        return viewType;
    }

    // For feedItems
    private void bindFeedItemView(FeedViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final FeedItemView feedItemView = viewHolder.feedItemView;
        final Feed feedDesign = feedItems.get(position);

        // TODO we can probably conditionally show or hide these based on the type of feed item, same as in FeedActivitySingle
        feedItemView.showOrHideEditButton(true);
        feedItemView.showOrHideBuyButton(false);
        feedItemView.showOrHideFlipButton(false);
        feedItemView.showOrHidePriceText(false);

        // Set the results into TextViews
        feedItemView.setProductPriceText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getPrice()));
        feedItemView.setDownloadsText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getDownloadCount()));
        feedItemView.setLikesText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getLikesCount()));
        feedItemView.setUsernameText(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getUsername());
        feedItemView.setTimestampText(feedDesign.getTimestampText());
        feedItemView.getSaveImage().setImageResource(feedDesign.isInPersonalGallery() ? R.drawable.ic_action_saved : R.drawable.ic_not_saved);
        feedItemView.getLikeImage().setImageResource(feedDesign.isLiked() ? R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed_full : R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed);

        feedItemView.getTrashImage().setVisibility(ParseHelper.isCurrentUser(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getObjectId()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        feedItemView.getFeedSocialShareImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedImage().getUrl(), feedItemView.getImage(), feedItemView.getProgressBar());

        if(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getProfilePicture() != null) {
            feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getProfilePicture().getUrl(), feedItemView.getProfilePicture(), null); // TODO should this use profilePictureFileCache?
        } else {
            viewHolder.feedItemView.getProfilePicture().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_anonymous);
        }

        SetCommentViews(feedItemView, feedDesign.getComments());
        SetClickListeners(feedItemView, feedDesign);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getContentDataSize() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_FEED;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_AD;
        }
    }

    // Facebook Ad methods
    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

    }

    public void setFeedItemClickListener(FeedItemClickListener feedItemClickListener) {
        this.feedItemClickListener = feedItemClickListener;
    }

    private void SetCommentViews(FeedItemView feedItemView, List<Comment> comments) {

        feedItemView.getViewAllComments().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedItemView.setViewAllComments("View more comments");

        // reset layouts to hidden
        feedItemView.getComment1Layout().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        feedItemView.getComment2Layout().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        feedItemView.getComment3Layout().setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (comments == null || comments.size() == 0) {
            feedItemView.getViewAllComments().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        // note these are meant to fall-through without break statements
        switch (comments.size()) {
            case 3:
                feedItemView.getComment3Layout().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                feedItemView.setCommentUser3(comments.get(2).getAuthor().getUsername());
                feedItemView.setCommentText3(comments.get(2).getComment());
            case 2:
                feedItemView.getComment2Layout().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                feedItemView.setCommentUser2(comments.get(1).getAuthor().getUsername());
                feedItemView.setCommentText2(comments.get(1).getComment());
            case 1:
                feedItemView.getComment1Layout().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                feedItemView.setCommentUser1(comments.get(0).getAuthor().getUsername());
                feedItemView.setCommentText1(comments.get(0).getComment());
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SetClickListeners(final FeedItemView feedItemView, final Feed feedDesign) {

        // setup gesture detector with current view, view holder, and feed design
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener(feedDesign, feedItemView));

        // set gesture detector on image view
        feedItemView.setImageTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    if (isLongPressed){
                        isLongPressed = false;
                        feedItemClickListener.onMarkteFeedImageLongPressed_Release();
                        Log.d("anyTAG","Up");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_MOVE){
                    return true;
                }
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setTrashImageClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onTrashClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setFeedSocialShareClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                try {
                    feedItemClickListener.onSocialShareClicked(feedDesign);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setLikeImageClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onLikeClicked(feedDesign, feedItemView);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setSaveImageClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onSaveClicked(feedDesign, feedItemView);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setAuthorClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onAuthorClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setCommentTextClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onCreateCommentClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setViewAllCommentsClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onCreateCommentClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setEditImageClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onCreateEditImageClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setCommentImageClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onCreateCommentClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setCommentUser1ClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onAuthorClicked(feedDesign.getComments().get(0).getAuthor().getObjectId());
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setCommentUser2ClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onAuthorClicked(feedDesign.getComments().get(1).getAuthor().getObjectId());
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setCommentUser3ClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onAuthorClicked(feedDesign.getComments().get(2).getAuthor().getObjectId());
            }
        });

        feedItemView.setProfilePictureClickListener(v -> {
            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onProfilePictureClicked(feedDesign);
            }
        });

    }

    class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        FeedItemView feedItemView;

        public FeedViewHolder(FeedItemView view) {
            super(view);
            this.feedItemView = view;
        }

    }

    // Gesture detector for double tap
    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private Feed feedDesign;
        private FeedItemView feedItemView;

        public GestureListener(Feed feedDesign, FeedItemView feedItemView) {
            this.feedDesign = feedDesign;
            this.feedItemView = feedItemView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("FeedRecyclerAdapter", feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedImage().getUrl());

            if (feedItemClickListener != null) {
                feedItemClickListener.onImageDoubleTapped(feedDesign, feedItemView);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if (!isLongPressed){
                    isLongPressed = true;
                    feedItemClickListener.onMarketFeedImageLongPressed(feedDesign, feedDesign.getDisplayedSide());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
07-01 16:32:12.509 23168-23168/com.elgami.customizer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.elgami.customizer, PID: 23168
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.facebook.ads.NativeAd com.facebook.ads.NativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd()' on a null object reference
at com.elgami.feed.FeedRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FeedRecyclerAdapter.java:121)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Ha
```

**To begin with, it seems to be complaining about this line:**

```
nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();
```

**Here is a gist of my FeedActivity class:**

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd1b6afd21d27744a99970d3f51aa8a0

Comment: That error indicates that `manager` is `null` when you're trying to call `nextNativeAd` on it. You should double-check that you're actually passing a valid manager to your constructor.

Comment: How would I determine that?

Comment: You could start by looking where you're calling `new FeedRecyclerAdapter(...)` and check for example that you don't accidentally pass a literal `null` value as `manager` argument to your constructor. If you don't immediately see why you're getting a `null` there, hook up a debugger to better understand what's going on with your program while it's running. There are good tips at http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1321716. If you still can't figure it out, update your code to add some more code, so others can try to help you out.

Comment: I call this constructor in the onCreate method of my FeedActivity, which is separate from my FeedRecyclerAdapter: ``feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(this, feedItems, new ImageLoader(new FeedItemFileCache(this)), nativeAd, manager);``. I added the activity in my edit if you want to give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` occurs when you try to call a method or access a field of an object reference, but that reference does not hold a valid object. A simple example would be:

```
String someString;
char firstChar = someString.charAt(0); // ERROR!
```

This code throws an error because the `someString` variable does not reference a valid `String` instance when `charAt` is called. Notice that the first line **does not create** a `String` instance, it only declares a variable that may *point* to a `String`. In fact, this code is *equivalent* to:

```
String someString = null;
char firstChar = someString.charAt(0);
```

For more information about `NullPointerException`s, why they occur and how you can fix them: [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1321716).

In your case, the error is caused by [line 176 in `FeedActivity`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd1b6afd21d27744a99970d3f51aa8a0#file-feedactivity-L176):

```
feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(this, feedItems, new ImageLoader(new FeedItemFileCache(this)), nativeAd, manager);
```

Here, `manager` is an instance field of the `FeedActivity` class, defined on [line 87](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd1b6afd21d27744a99970d3f51aa8a0#file-feedactivity-L87):

```
public NativeAdsManager manager;
```

The problem is that **this field is never assigned a value**: there are no assignments to this field (such as `manager = ...`). As such, when line 176 is executed, the `FeedRecyclerAdapter` receives `null` as its `manager` argument, and throws a `NullPointerException` later on in `onBindViewHolder` when it tries to use that `manager`.

The solution is to create a valid `NativeAdsManager` in your `FeedActivity` and assign it to `manager` before passing it to `FeedRecyclerAdapter`. [From the Facebook documentation about `NativeAdsManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/nativeadsmanager), such code should look like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements NativeAdsManager.Listener {

    private NativeAdsManager manager; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        manager = new NativeAdsManager(this, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", 5);
        manager.setListener(this);
        manager.loadAds();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to initialize in the main feed activity. Solved this exception at least!